# Colors on my MacBook wrong every morning when computer wakes up

Tags: macos, mac, display

Every morning, the colors on my MacBook are dim.  I can barely read the text on the screen.  This is true for both the built in screen and my external monitor.  If I go to the Display settings and change the color profile to something else, and then back to the normal profile, it fixes the problem until the next time.

NightShift schedule says Off, so I don't think that's it.  I've also tried choosing different profiles, and that didn't help.

Comment: Could it be NightShift? System Preferences > Displays > Night Shift.

Comment: If not night shift, then just as a test set it to a different profile before letting it sleep, see if a similar thing happens.

Comment: NightShift schedule says off, so I don't think it's that.

Comment: So, if you let it go to sleep in the afternoon, and then wake it, do you get the same behaviour, or not?

Comment: It went to sleep this morning, and didn't have trouble.  It seems to happen when I first wake it up each day.